# Y a-t-il un équivalent français de l'expression « cellar door »?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, prononciation

L'expression « *cellar door* » en anglais est censée être la [plus belle expression de la langue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellar_door).  (Même si, moi, je ne le trouve pas specialement belle).  Est ce qu'il ya une phrase française qui est consideré « belle » de la même manière que « *cellar door* » ?

Comment: Attention : il s'agit de l'expression anglaise qui est, soit-disant, la plus harmonieuse du point de vue de l'euphonie (peut-on dire la plus euphonique ?) pas la plus belle tout court. Les critères de beauté pourraient être autres...

Comment: J'abonde tout à fait dans le sens de Laure : en l'état, ça ne ressemble à une question très subjective, à fermer. Rajouter une mention de l'euphonie me semble important.

Answer (score 6):

Je n'ai malheureusement aucune source, c'est à creuser, mais il me semble qu'en français, ce sont surtout les mots de trois syllabes contenant les voyelles [i] [a] [o] qui sonnent le mieux. Ce serait d'ailleurs pour ceci que Guillaume Apollinaire aurait écrit le poème « Le Pont Mirabeau » (qui en soi n'est pas le plus beau pont de Paris).

Notons que ces voyelles sont également les favorites des chats. Je ne parle pas du « miaou » stylisé, mais du son réel que font les chats.

Comment: [À la _mi-août_, c'est tellement plus romantique](http://www.frmusique.ru/texts/j/jeunesse_l/alamiaout.htm)